# How to transform table data to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have csv file containing 3 columns: name, position and plays (plays has value 1 if player plays at that position, otherwise has value 0). One player can play more than one position. There are no two players with the same name. Sample data:

```
Brian,goalkeeper,0
Brian,fullback,1
Brian,playmaker,1
Brian,centerback,0
Brian,striker,0
Teddy,goalkeeper,0
Teddy,fullback,0
Teddy,playmaker,1
Teddy,centerback,1
Teddy,striker,1
Alan,goalkeeper,1
Alan,fullback,0
Alan,playmaker,0
Alan,centerback,1
Alan,striker,0
```

I want to transform this data to data frame, to have names in rows, positions as column names, and values 0/1 as data in cells.

```
players <-read.csv("players.csv", sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

command

```
table1 <-    table(players$name,players$position,players$plays)
```

gives me two tables

```
        centerback fullback goalkeeper playmaker striker
  Alan           0        1          0         1       1
  Brian          1        0          1         0       1
  Teddy          0        1          1         0       0

and 
        centerback fullback goalkeeper playmaker striker
  Alan           1        0          1         0       0
  Brian          0        1          0         1       0
  Teddy          1        0          0         1       1
```

(Why is table function doing this?, second one is correct for me). How is it possible to transform table1 to data frame, to have player names in rows, positions as column names, and values 0/1 as data in cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table is giving you an 3-D array because you have 3-variables to take into consideration, You need to drop one of them, ie only subset to get where `plays == 1` then do a table on that.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(subset(players, plays == 1, -plays)))
      centerback fullback goalkeeper playmaker striker
Alan           1        0          1         0       0
Brian          0        1          0         1       0
Teddy          1        0          0         1       1
```

Or you could also use `xtabs` as below:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(plays~name + position, players))
      centerback fullback goalkeeper playmaker striker
Alan           1        0          1         0       0
Brian          0        1          0         1       0
Teddy          1        0          0         1       1
```

If you need the names as a column, use reshape:

```
reshape(df, timevar = 'position', idvar = 'name', direction = 'wide', sep='_')
    name plays_goalkeeper plays_fullback plays_playmaker plays_centerback plays_striker
1  Brian                0              1               1                0             0
6  Teddy                0              0               1                1             1
11  Alan                1              0               0                1             0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` for this.

```
library(tidyr)
players %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = position, values_from = plays)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  name  goalkeeper fullback playmaker centerback striker
  <chr>      <int>    <int>     <int>      <int>   <int>
1 Brian          0        1         1          0       0
2 Teddy          0        0         1          1       1
3 Alan           1        0         0          1       0
```